# Applying a Function to a Data Frame : lapply vs traditional way

Tags: r, data-manipulation

I have this data frame in R:

```
x <- seq(1, 10,0.1)
y <- seq(1, 10,0.1)
data_frame <- expand.grid(x,y)
```

I also have this function:

```
some_function <- function(x,y) { return(x+y) }
```

Basically, I want to create a new column in the data frame based on "some_function". I thought I could do this with the "lapply" function in R:

```
data_frame$new_column <-lapply(c(data_frame$x, data_frame$y),some_function)
```

This does not work:

```
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, f, value = list()) : 
  replacement has 0 rows, data has 8281
```

I know how to do this in a more "clunky and traditional" way:

```
data_frame$new_column = x + y
```

But I would like to know how to do this using "lapply" - in the future, I will have much more complicated and longer functions that will be a pain to write out like I did above. Can someone show me how to do this using "lapply"?

Thank you!

Comment: You could do `transform(data_frame, new_column=some_function(x,y))`. This works well because your function is vectorized. Using `lapply` here would be a poor choice. If you want to apply over multiple columns, `mapply()` or `Map()` are better options, but only if your function is not already vectorized

Comment: Thank you! This seems to have fixed it! :)

Comment: Not sure what is "clunky" about `data_frame$new_column <- data_frame$Var1 + data_frame$Var2`, but `data_frame$new_column <-mapply(some_function, data_frame$Var1, data_frame$Var2)` also works. In your example, `data_frame` does not contain any variables, x, y, but instead Var1 and Var2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When working within a `data.frame` you could use `apply` instead of `lapply`:

```
x <- seq(1, 10,0.1)
y <- seq(1, 10,0.1)
data_frame <- expand.grid(x,y)
head(data_frame)
some_function <- function(x,y) { return(x+y) }

data_frame$new_column <- apply(data_frame, 1, \(x) some_function(x["Var1"], x["Var2"]))
head(data_frame)
```

To apply a function to rows set `MAR = 1`, to apply a function to columns set `MAR = 2`.

`lapply`, as the name suggests, is a ***l**ist*-apply. As a `data.frame` is a list of columns you can use it to compute over columns but within rectangular data, `apply` is often the easiest.

If `some_function` is written for that specific purpose, it can be written to accept a single row of the data.frame as in

```
x <- seq(1, 10,0.1)
y <- seq(1, 10,0.1)
data_frame <- expand.grid(x,y)
head(data_frame)

some_function <- function(row) { return(row[1]+row[2]) }

data_frame$yet_another <- apply(data_frame, 1, some_function)
head(data_frame)
```

*Final comment:* Often functions written for only a pair of values come out as perfectly vectorized. Probably the best way to call `some_function` is without any function of the `apply`-familiy as in

```
some_function <- function(x,y) { return(x + y) }
data_frame$last_one <- some_function(data_frame$Var1, data_frame$Var2)
```